# How to add a value of a tag to the href of another tag using only HTML (no script)

Tags: html

Java script isn't working on the website I am trying to use. So I am trying to do it with just HTML

Here is the code:

```
 <input type="text" name="tf" id="txt"  value="txtToAddToHrefInTagA">


 <a id="pp" href="https://www.google.com/#q=" target=">_blank">

 <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_ASd3nWdw8qI/TUkLNXmQwgI/AAAAAAAAAiE/XxYLicNBdqQ/s1600/Search_Feb_02_Main.png"  alt="Pay Now" /></a>
```

I am trying to add "txtToAddToHrefInTagA" to "https://www.google.com/#q=" so that the  tag href="https://www.google.com/#q=txtToAddToHrefInTagA". So that a new page will open with google searching for "txtToAddToHrefInTagA"

All the info I could find had javascript. Does anyone know how to do it with just HTML?

So far I randomly tried:

```
 href="https://www.google.com/#q=" + document.getElementById('txt').value
```

But of course it didn't work.

Also, if you know why typing into the text field doesn't change the value of the input tag that will help solve my next problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible without script. btw. `document.getElementById(...)` is a script already, isn't it?

Comment: can you use server-side code? Is JavaScript just disabled in your browser? Or is there something you could do to enable it? As far as I know, JavaScript, something similar, or a server-side program is the only way to do this

Comment: Thanks for your comments. JavaScript seems blocked on the website I'm using. I cant enable it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a form.

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @elreimundo it seems like a good answer but when I tried running it I got this problem: the browser would not go to google.com, it said "waiting for google.com" in the bottom of the browser for a moment, then the screen flickered and nothing happened? I have had this problem before and cant find the cause?

Comment: I was told here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026038/submitting-a-html-form-to-go-to-a-url-does-not-load-the-webpage-it-starts-to-lo That google does not allow it. Thanks for the answer though